# Insert in nullable FK

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table X has some fields and one of them is the FK representing the id of another table Y, the FK does not necessarily need to be filled, so I set it as Nullable, but when I'm going to insert in laravel or  phpmyadmin to test, the following message is returned 
`# 1452 - Can not add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

I wonder how I can do this insert allowing me to leave the null FK.

Comment: Si preguntas en ingles, más gente puede apoyarte! Lo siento, no hablo portugués....

Comment: The Portugese site is http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry, i translate the question

Comment: You'll probably need to share either some PHP code or the CREATE TABLE statement (whatever Lavarel uses). That error message contradicts your statement that you are leaving the column NULL.

Comment: Keep in mind that zero or empty string is not the same as NULL. So if you insert the value `''` it won't work.